# Oracle multiple partition selection

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, database-partitioning

I have a query that selects from multiple partitions

```
select * from table partition (P1), table2, table3, table4
union all
select * from table partition (P2), table2, table3, table4
....
select * from table partition (P12), table2, table3, table4
```

Table has over 30,331,246 entry's in the 12 partitions. I need to find a faster way to pull up the result (now it takes approx 35min). If I do select from the table not the partition the time will be over 135min but it's not how a query should look.

Could you please assist me in finding another way to do this ?

Comment: What are the join criteria (WHERE clause, INNER/OUTER JOIN) between `table`, `table2`, `table3`, `table4`? Are there any indexes? Are there any WHERE clauses to subset the data? What column is `table` partitioned on? Are there other partitions than P1 through P12? How many rows in each of the table2 through table4? Please edit your question and include this information. Thanks.

Comment: perhaps a nolock keyword can help you ?

Comment: @ah_hau there is no such thing as `nolock` in Oracle. Readers never block writers there.